# Creating shapefile of concentric circles around point on map using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon-creation, circle

I am trying to model sound propagation from a moving sound source. I have a csv file with lat, long of the source with timestamps every 10 seconds. What I'm trying to do is draw concentric circles around the source location up to 100 km, in 50 m increment. This should be a shapefile for every timestamp.

I was able to use fiona to create static circle shapefile but multiple concentric circles are throwing me off.

This is the code I used to draw circle around a point:

```py
p = shapely.geometry.Point([-90.0667, 29.9500]) # location

n_points = 20
d = 10 * 1000  # meters
angles = np.linspace(0, 360, n_points)
polygon = geog.propagate(p, angles, d) # draws a 20 point circle around the location
```

The demoTrack file looks like this:

```
Time               Name Lattitude    Longitude
2021-09-12 23:13    H   44.63   -63.56
2021-09-14 23:13    H   43.78   -62
2021-09-16 23:14    H   44.83   -54.6
2021-09-18 23:14    H   35.55   -38.24
2021-09-20 23:14    H   41.17   -24
2021-09-22 23:14    H   37.447  -17.616
2021-09-24 23:14    H   35.932  -7.328
2021-09-26 23:14    H   34.417  2.96
```

Combining with folium map, and moving sound source, the code looked like this:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
import numpy as np
import json
import geog
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd

# Make a standard map
m = folium.Map(location=[44.63, -63.56], zoom_start=6)

tracks = pd.read_csv("demoTrack.csv") # Location of the moving sound source with timestamps

# Make a coordinates pair for the track
track = []  # holds the trajectory
for i in range(len(tracks)):
    c = (tracks.iloc[i]["Longitude"], tracks.iloc[i]["Lattitude"])
    track.append(c)

# Make the time type string to make it JSON convertible
times = tracks["Time"].astype('str')
times = [times[i] for i in range(len(times))]

# Make a line feature for the track
path = {
    'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': track
            },
    'properties':
    {
                'times': times,
                'style':
                    {
                        'color': 'red'
                    }
            }
}

# one feature to cycle through all the locations (this is the radius circle)
poly = []
for i in track:
    p = shapely.geometry.Point(i)

    n_points = 20
    d = 100 * 1000  # meters
    angles = np.linspace(0, 360, n_points)
    polygon = geog.propagate(p, angles, d)
    poly.append(shapely.geometry.mapping(shapely.geometry.Polygon(polygon)))  # Append the polygon coordinates directly

# Add the polygons as a column to the tracks dataframe
tracks["Polygon"] = pd.Series([i["coordinates"] for i in poly])

# Now creating the polygon feature using the Polygon column
radiusCircle = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'MultiPolygon',
        'coordinates': tracks["Polygon"].tolist()
    },
    'properties': {
        'style': {
            'color': 'yellow',
        },
        'times': times
    }
}

# Now make a line feature to plot the track
TimestampedGeoJson(
    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [path, radiusCircle]},
    period='P1D',
    duration='P1M',
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options='YYYY/MM/DD',
).add_to(m)

m.save('timeSlider.html')
```

This code basically draws the path and the radius circle around the location. I want to scale this now and achieve two things: (1) Instead of just one circle, make 2000 concentric circles around the point and (2) Turn the concentric circles into a shapefile to be used later.

I can't figure out how to efficiently create coordinates for 2000 circles and to also convert them into a shapefile.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the csv file as text to you question?

Comment: @BERA Edited my question to include it.